# wordpress/ visual composer shortcode not updating on mobile device

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

This really basic shortcode works fine on PC (I.E., Firefox) ~ as in each time I reload the webpage calling the shortcode, it displays a new random number.  However it does not work on mobile device (it is just stuck on the same/first generated number all the time), even if I close the browser and re-open.  Any suggestions?

```
function shortcode_mytable( $atts ){
$rand_var=rand();
return $rand_var;       
}
add_shortcode( 'mytable', 'shortcode_mytable' );
```

Comment: Also, confirmed that this is not browser related.  Example, the function works on Firefox on PC, but not Firefox on an android device (not sure about apple device)

Comment: This almost certainly sounds like a browser caching issue - the code being run is php and is on the server, the client device should not affect the result of the shortcode at all.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I was thinking along those lines too -- but not sure if in my php shortcode code I can clear the browser, at least on mobile devices?  Anyone know?

Comment: Do you have any caching in the wordpress site? Any plugins that cache anything?

Comment: I did not intentionally do any caching in the wordpress site... so unless it is default option in wordpress, I don't think so.  As a debug measure, I stripped the site down as much as I could to basically just that chunk of code above, and one visual-composer page to display it.

Comment: I also just cleared the cache, cookies, history on my phone and still it is not working (not getting a random number on the phone version)... very strange.  Code works fine on PC and I have not had to clear the cache at all.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page in question please?

Comment: Sure:  http://www.feedodger.com/results/  {all this page is doing is calling the shortcode above through the shortcode mapper [and not passing any variables in the shortcode]}

Comment: On chrome I am seeing the same number on the page every time; it is not changing at all, even after hard refresh with cache removal. I am seeing this in the page source:

<!--Generated by Endurance Page Cache-->

Are you *sure* you have no caching on?

Comment: Thanks for checking Chris.  Hmm, not sure on the caching - as mentioned earlier, I did not intentionally turn any caching on in wordpress --- but can investigate ~ I am not too familiar with caching

Comment: Endurance page cache is a plugin added by your webhost to help caching of all pages. I suggest you contact them about it.

Comment: Excellent, will do - I really appreciate your inputs and patience - thanks Chris